# Neural network coordinate features

Tags: neural-network, coordinates, feature-selection

In his publication "[Giraffe: Using Deep Reinforcement Learning to Play Chess](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01549)" Matthew Lai writes of representing the chess game positions as a list of pieces and their coordinates rather than using the conventional approach of representing each 64 tiles of the board by 12 binary values for absence/presence of a piece.
As an example he gives:

[image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaH2T.png)

But how would one achieve encoding a position like "b7" from a software point of view in a neural network? Is the approach of having two input neurons for every position of a piece as x and y varying from 1-8, e.g. 2 and 7 for "b7" too naive? Is there a better solution?

Comment: You do not have to have two coordinates. you could just have one number, 1 - 64. So a1 could be 1 and h8 would be 64. b7 could be 15 in this notation.

Comment: Yeah, i thought of this as well. Would i need to normalize those values? I'm rather new to this but wouldn't such values cause complications like being to dominative on the outcome?